# dd corrupts my SD card

Tags: sd-card, partition

I have encountered the following issue with the installation of RASPBIAN on my RPi Model B. I have downloaded the raspbian image but when I flash it on my SD card via `sudo dd bs=1M if=image.img of=/dev/sdb1`, which, besides, returns no errors, I end up with a corrupted partition table at `/dev/sdb` (checked it using gparted). I cannot fathom what's happening, provided that both the image is ok and my drive is unmounted prior to dumping.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't `of` be `/dev/sdb` instead of `sdb1`?

Comment: But, should I define the partition?

Comment: It worked!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`of` should be `/dev/sdb`

You write the image to the card, not to a specific partition of the card. The image in itself contains partitions - that is why it shows up as corrupt in gparted.